# Dynamically changing Image URLs in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I'm trying to set the image URL dynamically. The images are locally stored and their location paths are in a JSON file.

**JSON File**

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "cat1",
      "name": "Burgers",
      "itemCount": 10,
      "images":{
        "main":"./../images/items/Burgers.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "cat2",
      "name": "Pizzas",
      "itemCount": 5,
      "images":{
        "main":"./../images/items/Pizzas.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code**

```
renderItem: function (item) {
    var imageURL = require(item.images.main);
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Image source={imageURL} style={styles.image}>
                <Text style={styles.textMain}>{item.name}</Text>
            </Image>
        </View>
    );
}
```

This gives the following error.

*2015-12-10 16:02:45.295 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "./../images/items/Burger.jpg". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.*

But if I replace ***var imageURL = require(item.images.main);*** with ***var imageURL = require("./../images/items/Pizzas.jpg");*** it shows the image perfectly.

What is causing this? How do this correctly?

Comment: The exception complains about `Burger.jpg` missing. When you hard-code the string `Pizzas.jpg`, it works. Are you sure that `Burger.jpg` isn't just missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the require(PATH) method actually make the packager try and resolve the image during packaging which it can't do if its just looking at a variable. I would try doing:

```
<Image source={{uri: image.images.main}} />
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. I'm doing it in my app at the moment. I'm getting no errors, but my images aren't displaying. Why is it so hard to show images that come from an api?!

Comment: You need to specify dimensions if you're loading from url. <Image source={{uri: image.images.main}} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />

Answer (score 1):

We need to `require` the image before using it.

Something like this;

`const image = require("../../assets/someImage.png");`

`<Image source={image} />`

This thing worked for me.

Comment: How will you convert it from require to uri?

Comment: @LuvnishMonga You can do something like this. 





<Image
        source={{
          uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
        }}
      />